# Как правильно сделать v-model у компонента?

Tags: vue.js

InputName.vue

```
<template>
  <el-form-item label="Название" prop="name">
    <el-input :value="name" @input="updateName"></el-input>
  </el-form-item>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "InputName",
  props: ["name"],
  methods: {
    updateName() {
      this.$emit("input", name);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Используется в форме

```
<el-form ref="form" :model="form">
   <input-name v-model="name" />
</el-form>
```

Пишет что 'Property or method "name" is not defined'. В чем моя ошибка, и как сделать чтобы все работало?

Comment: Так а на какую строку он ругается? Полный трейс бы показать. И вы же дали часть когда, мне кажется что тут - <input-name v-model="name" />, а не в компоненте

Comment: А как у `<el-input>` получить значение?

Comment: Это мне вопрос? При инпуте срабатывает метод updateNames, который эмитит в родительский элемент.

Comment: Нет, как значение `value` у `el-input` получить? Для ответа нужно.

Comment: Yaroslav, так проблема не в компоненте? В консоли я не уверен что возможно узнать на конкретно какую строку ругается, но ругается на компонент в котором он находится.

Comment: Блин, действительно, ошибка в том что в v-model нужно писать было "form.name". Но проблема сильно не решилась, потому что в инпуты писать нельзя, просто буквы не появляются

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В официальной документации `Vue` - [Использование v-model на компонентах](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-v-model-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85) подробно описано, как работает `v-model` на компонентах:

> Не забывайте, что:
>
> `<input v-model="searchText">`
>
> делает то же самое, что и:
>
> `<input v-bind:value="searchText" v-on:input="searchText = $event.target.value">`

> При использовании на компоненте, `v-model` делает следующее:

```
<custom-input
  v-bind:value="searchText"
  v-on:input="searchText = $event"
></custom-input>
```

> Чтобы это действительно работало, элемент  внутри компонента должен:

1. Привязывать значение атрибута `value` к входному параметру `value`
2. По событию `input` генерировать собственное пользовательское событие `input` с новым значением

К сожалению в вашем коде не описаны все используемые вами компоненты (что не дает возможности проанализировать код), поэтому приведу наглядный пример двунаправленной связи между компонентами через `v-model`:

```js
Vue.component('input-name', {
  props: ["value", "name"],
  methods: {
    updateName(e) {
      this.$emit("input", e.target.value);
    }
  },
  template: `
  <div>
  <label>
    [component - input-name] {{ name }}
    <input :value="value" @input="updateName"></input>
  </label>
  </div>
`
})
Vue.component('el-form', {
  props: ["value"],
  template: `
  <div>
  [component - el-form]
  <pre>{{ JSON.stringify(value, 0, 2) }}</pre>
  <hr>
  <slot name="default"></slot>
  </div>
`
})

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    form: {
      name: 'Test Name',
      family: 'Test Family'
    }
  }
})
```

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <el-form ref="form" v-model="form">
    <input-name v-for="(field, key) in form" :key="key" :name="key" v-model="form[key]" />
  </el-form>
</div>
```